# DataGrid: Dyanmically adding rows

Tags: c#, windows, datagrid

I am new to windows application. I need to add rows in the DataGrid dynamically which has person data. when i do the following is see only the last person in the last row. i see rows populating but with no data. If i do a break on the first fetch i do get the right one. But something is wrong. Any ideas

```
foreach (var p in personList)
        {

            gvAdminSummary.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
            gvAdminSummary.Rows[gvAdminSummary.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value = p.FName;
            gvAdminSummary.Rows[gvAdminSummary.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = p.LName;
            gvAdminSummary.Rows[gvAdminSummary.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2].Value = p.PNo;


        }
```

Comment: Is this a data-bound grid?  If so, you should add to the data source and not the grid itself.

Comment: I would try to MessageBox.Show gvAdminSummary.Rows.Count every cycle. Is it updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGridRowView.Add method accepts string arrays:

```
gvAdminSummary.Rows.Add( { p.FName, p.LName, p.PNo });
```

Likely, though, there's a better solution for you in binding the grid directly to your person list.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the right approach.  Create a BindingSource and bind a collection of your objects to it.  Then bind the BindingSource to the Grid's data source.  Make sure your objects implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  This way, whenever, you add an object to the collection, or change a property within your object, it'll automatically reflect in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `DataGridView`, but if you want to stick to inserting data into the control directly, why not use `ListView` instead?  It has an API more suited to your current needs or way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Either

gvAdminSummary.Datasource = persons;
gvAdminSummary.databind();

Or

foreach (var p in personList)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
            dr.cells.add(new datagridcell()) etc..  populate cells
            gvAdminSummary.Rows.add(dr);

```
    }
```